# 401 from _vti_bin/client.svc from within SharePoint 2013 updating list

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication

I've recently upgraded to SharePoint 2013 from 2010.

I'm getting a repeated 401 unauthorized when trying to update a List. This issue also occurs when trying to change permissions.

The 401 is being returned from `http://{webapp domain name}/{site collection}/{site}/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery`

This occurs on all of the sites as part of the web application.

We're running Kerberos on that site. SharePoint version 15.0.4617.1000

I have a support case logged with MS at the moment, but I feel like I'm going around in circles with them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might need to you try deactivate  the “HTTP Activation” feature of .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.5 and re-enabled one by one (1st .NET 3.5, 2nd .NET 4.5 ) them after deactivation then do the IISReset

Comment: just ran through that.
with http activation completely disabled updating lists failed immediately (no auth prompt) - so I think we're on the right track here.
I re-enabled http acivation in 3.5 and then 4.5 and it's gone back to 401ing.

Comment: did you do the iisrest afterwards?

Comment: yes I did. I'm giving it a reboot now to see if that helps at all.

Comment: same thing sorry. here's the script I ran
remove-windowsfeature NET-HTTP-Activation
remove-windowsfeature NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45
add-windowsfeature NET-HTTP-Activation
add-windowsfeature NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45
add-windowsfeature AS-HTTP-Activation
iisreset

Comment: have a look this link. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ff191f26-a467-4103-a09a-6f0fe2012d50/vtibinclientsvcprocessquery-post-401?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: that's absolutely crazy - re-enabling forms auth made the issue go away. I have actually performed those steps previous to posting / getting MS involved, so I wonder if doing the HTTP activation steps in the order you described and re-enabling forms has resolved the fault. Either way, thank you, it's looking good!

Comment: no worries. glad i can help

Comment: I just make add an answered for the sake to close this ticket and to help other if having the same issue that you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You might need to you try deactivate the “HTTP Activation” feature of .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.5 and re-enabled one by one (1st .NET 3.5, 2nd .NET 4.5 ) them after deactivation then do the IISReset
2. Re-enable Form Authentication

Link:http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ff191f26-a467-4103-a09a-6f0fe2012d50/vtibinclientsvcprocessquery-post-401?forum=sharepointadmin